# Speeding search folder path in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 and trying to **search folder not file**.

We have specific project number for every project and evry documents goes to project folder under any project. So , we have to search the project folder if it is exist or valid.

My script can find the specific folder but it takes long time (about 11 to 13 minutes to complete the process)

I would like to share my script work to have some better ideas.

```
import os                            

path=r"F:\Projekte"

def find_directory():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for i in dirs:
            if i=="A9901001":
                print root

find_directory()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not execute linux `find` command or `tree` commands (`FIND` in case of windows) in python . Commands like `find` would use system indexes and probably give a faster result.

Something like:-
    `find . -type d -name "A9901001"`

Python code should look something like this

```
import os
paths = os.system('find . -type d -name "A9901001"')
```

Note:- Follow this solution only if you are getting some performance, since your initial approach is certainly more elegant.

Comment: I am using windows and I run your@hspandher suggested code. It returns me 1 . Is it possible to get full path.

Answer (score 1):

why no just this?

```
def find_directory():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if "A9901001" in dirs:
            print(root, "A9901001")
```

and if you have a chace to use python3: there is [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) which does similar things as `os.walk` but is a lot faster on NTFS.

Comment: my python is linked with ArcGIS 10.4 and I am working for developing tools for ArcGIS  using its utility. Is is possible to stop looping after I have my folder?

Comment: oh, i see. a different option would be to run the directory scans 'offline' in the background; collect the directory names in a kind of database (e.g. just a python dictionary - or sqlite or something). getting results from there should be almost instantly. you'd have to `walk` the directory tree from time to time in order to update the 'database'.